# how to update a bunch of entities with one async call(submit)

Tags: c#, silverlight-5.0, wcf-ria-services

Suppose I have table Mytab in my database like:

```
MyTab(ID, col1, col2, col3,col4)
```

With EF, I have an entity named MyTab. With WCF RIA SERVICES, I can update data by SubmitChanges at Silverlight on the client side.

Then I have a list of data for this entity at client side:

```
ID    col3
1     A
2     B
3     C
4     D
5     E
```

I want to update Col3 for all those data in the list. Then I need populate each entity by WCF RIA Services firstly, then change col3 for each entity in entity collection, then submit change. If I have 1000 records in the list, I will have 1000 async calls to populate each entity with the ID.

I have no query to get all entities with those IDs, because no rules for this IDs in the list.

Any solution could with one async call to send all database to server to update data in DB?

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would use an invoke operation on the service. That way you simply invoke the method and there is no need to previously load any entity to the client.

To do so first create an invoke operation on your service

```csharp
[EnableClientAccess]
public class MyDomainService : DomainService
{
    [Invoke(HasSideEffects = true)]
    public void UpdateCol3OfAllEntities()
    {
        // Use you data access layer to perform the neccessary
        // query: "UPDATE MyTab SET col3 = 'X'"...
    }
}
```

You can even extend the method by passing the ids to it:

```csharp
[Invoke(HasSideEffects = true)]
public void UpdateCol3OfAllEntitiesWithIds(int[] ids)
{
    // Use you data access layer to perform the neccessary
    // query: "UPDATE MyTab SET col3 = 'X' WHERE id IN (...)"...
}
```

Then simply invoke that on the client side:

```csharp
var context = new MyDomainContext();
context.UpdateCol3OfAllEntities(operation => 
    {
        if (operation.HasError)
        {
            // If in trouble or in doubt, run in circles, scream and shout!
            operation.MarkErrorAsHandled();
        }
        else
        {
            // Rejoice, for the operation succeeded!
        }
    }, null);
```

Note that the operation is decorated with the `InvokeAttribute`, which has set its `HasSideEffects`-parameter to `true`. That indicates that by invoking this method you acutally change something on the relevant data. See the MSDN for further details on that topic:

- on the [`InvokeAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.invokeattribute%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)
- on the [`HasSideEffects`-property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.domainservices.server.invokeattribute.hassideeffects%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)